# SharedPreferences get allways return default instead real value

Tags: java, get, hashmap, themes, settings

i saw some posts in this subject and try solution who didnt work .

i wrote in main activity :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);;
setTheme(sharedPreferences.getInt("selectedTheme", 0));
```

it allways return 0 .

i checked the Setting.xml file inside emulator :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<int name="STheme" value="2131099649" />
<int name="selectedTheme" value="2131099649" />
<string name="SThemeS">R.style.AppTheme</string>
</map>
```

as u can see the key value "selectedTheme" is there .

any ideas ?

another issue : will i have to create

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);;
```

for each activity that uses sharedPreferences  ?

Answer (score 2):

when SharedPreferences created the name of the file is as the activity that created him .

so if you create SharedPreferences  in Setting activity and you want to get preferences from other activity you have to spicify the name of SharedPreferences file .

if you trying to get preferences  from same activity you dont need to do that .

example :
SharedPreferences **created in Setting activiy** and reading it from diffrent activity :

add this line in current activity -

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Setting",
                MODE_PRIVATE)
```

and now you can pull the data....